# Node.js, IIS, Angular and Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, angularjs

So, I am a following a tutorial that uses angular seed to write my first angular application.

Angular seed comes with a `web-server.js` file that essentially runs a node server so you can emulate a web server.  The tutorial calls for starting the server in the command prompt.

The issue is that every time I run the file for starting the Node server, Visual Studio 2013 opens and then eventually tells me that access has been denied.  This is not the intended result.

Do I need to set up IIS for use with Node?  Why is VS opening when I start a node web server from the command prompt??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present .js files are configured to run with VS in your Windows.

http://nodejs.org/download/ -  you need to Download and Install node.js for Windows and make sure node is in PATH and you can run it from windows prompt `cmd`.

```
C:\> node -v
v0.10.22
```

To run angular seed web server, simply run go to the web-script.js's directory and run the it with node:

```
cd angular-seed/scripts
node web-server.js
```

Comment: I'm stupid.  All I had to do was prefix the `web-server.js` with the `node` command.  Thanks for this.